# Conditionally change the colour of Google calendar events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm using the below code to change the colour in Google calendar based on the name of the event.

I'm using a code snippet I found here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/85625/change-the-color-of-multiple-google-calendar-events. It runs, but doesn't actually change the colour. I checked the log and it seems to work until line 70, which is the end of the if statement that contains the colour codes.

```
function myFunction() {

var calendar = "myemail@something.com"; //The name of the calendar you want to modify (WITH quotes)

var startDate = new Date("Apr 01 GMT 2019"); //The start of the time range in which the events exist

var keyword = "Time sheets"; //The keyword to search for in the event title (WITH quotes; IS case-sensitive)

var where = 0;        //Where to search for events (0 = title; 1 = description)

var color = "blue"; //The color to change the events to (WITH the quotes)


var calendarId = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendar)[0].getId();

var optionalArgs = {
  timeMin: startDate.toISOString(),
  showDeleted: false,
  singleEvents: true,
  orderBy: 'startTime'
};


var service = Calendar.Events;
var response = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, optionalArgs);
var events = response.items;

for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {    
// Logger.log(events[i].summary);

  if (where == 0)
    var searchResult = events[i].summary.search(keyword);
  else if (where == 1){
    if (events[i].description == undefined)
      continue;

  var searchResult = events[i].description.search(keyword);
}

if (searchResult > -1){
  Logger.log(events[i].summary);


  if (color == "bold blue")
    events[i].colorId = 9;
  else if (color == "blue")
    events[i].colorId = 1;
  else if (color == "turquoise")
    events[i].colorId = 7;
  else if (color == "green")
    events[i].colorId = 2;
  else if (color == "bold green")
    events[i].colorId = 10;
  else if (color == "yellow")
    events[i].colorId = 5;
  else if (color == "orange")
    events[i].colorId = 6;
  else if (color == "red")
    events[i].colorId = 4;
  else if (color == "bold red")
    events[i].colorId = 11;
  else if (color == "purple")
    events[i].colorId = 3;
  else if (color == "gray")
    events[i].colorId = 8;
  Logger.log(events[i].colorId);


  try{
    service.update(events[i], calendarId, events[i].id);
  }
  catch(e){
    Logger.log(e);
    }
  }
 }
}
```

However, these lines don't seem to do anything?

```
      try{
    service.update(events[i], calendarId, events[i].id);
  }
  catch(e){
    Logger.log(e);
```

I'm new to Google AppScript and I don't understand what those last line of codes do and maybe I should use something with SetColor?

Comment: It's obvious that the line `service.update(events[i], calendarId, events[i].id);` is giving you an error. Could you tell which one is it? The `try catch` doesn't run because the code can't continue due to the error. I tried the code and it did change the colours of my events.

Comment: That's the thing, I didn't get an error message. However, I've found a different code snippet that I'm using now.

Comment: I see. Have you checked the logs in `View > Execution transcript`? Also, if you are using a different working code snippet, could you post it as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure. This is a very simple version, but the plan is to expand it.

```
function ColorEvents() {

var today = new Date();
var nextmonth = new Date();
nextmonth.setDate(nextmonth.getDate() + 30);
Logger.log(today + " " + nextmonth);

var calendars = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarsByName("someone@somewhere.com");
Logger.log("found number of calendars: " + calendars.length);

var calendar = calendars[0];

var events = calendar.getEvents(today, nextmonth);

for (var j=0; j<events.length; j++) {
  var e = events[j];

  var title = e.getTitle();
  Logger.log(title);
  var desc = e.getDescription();


  if (title == "Time sheets") {
    e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.CYAN);
   }
  } 
 }
```