# How to conditionally format in google calendar when title is longer than 1 character?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Apologies in advance for any unclarities, I am extremely new to coding.

I found this code by Rick Pastoor (https://rickpastoor.com/2019/05/30/google-calendar-color-coder.html) to automatically colour code events in my Google Calendar based on what character the events start with (in this case `!`, `[` and `#`).The code is for Google Apps Script

```
function ColorEvents() {
  var today = new Date();
  var nextweek = new Date();
  nextweek.setDate(nextweek.getDate() + 7);
  Logger.log(today + " " + nextweek);
  var calendars = CalendarApp.getAllOwnedCalendars();
  Logger.log("found number of calendars: " + calendars.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < calendars.length; i++) {
    var calendar = calendars[i];
    var events = calendar.getEvents(today, nextweek);
    for (var j = 0; j < events.length; j++) {
      var e = events[j];
      var title = e.getTitle();
      if (title[0] == "[") {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.CYAN);
      }
      if (title[0] == "!") {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.RED);
      }
      if (title[0] == '#') {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.GREEN);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now instead of an event starting with `!`, I want it to colour code if an event starts with a word say:

```
if (title[0] == "Vacation") {
      e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.RED);
```

This however doesn't work. Anything with just one character (letters, numbers, signs) work, but more than 1 character doesn't work and I was wondering how I could solve this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I found another link to a code that works somewhat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249958/conditionally-change-the-colour-of-google-calendar-events?rq=1

Here the problem I face is that the colour only changes when the title is exactly (for e.g.) the word 'Vacation'. What I'm looking for is a combination of these two codes? If I make two events 'Meeting: Sally' and Meeting: Mark' I want both to change colour by triggering the word 'Meeting' if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (title[0] == "!") {
```

#### To:

```
if ((/^Vacation/).test(title)) {
```

- For example, if you want to ignore the uppercase and lowercase, you can use `if ((/^Vacation/i).test(title)) {`.

#### Reference:

- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer! Sadly this doesn't seem to do anything. I tried using both your examples, differents words, putting it in front and after but the colours won't change. I tried just your suggestions without the other title == x 
I understand I don't have a large knowledge of code so I'm not exactly sure what everything means. I even looked at your reference and played around a little with how they write it but nothing. Nevertheless thank you so much for taking time to answer I appreciate it! :)

Comment: @Ruby Thank you for replying. I forgot to remove `[0]`. I apologize for this. So, I modified the above modification. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed it and it works perfectly now :)

Comment: @Ruby Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

`title[0]` returns the first character of the event title, however you are looking to match more than the first character.

To match all event titles that **contain** the word "Vacation" you could do:

```
if (title.includes("Vacation")) {
  e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.RED);
}
```

To match all events titles that are **exactly equal** to the word "Vacation" you could do:

```
if (title === "Vacation") {
  e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.RED);
}
```

To match only event titles that **begin with** the word "Vacation" you could do:

```
const searchWord = "Vacation"
if (title.slice(0, searchWord.length) === searchWord) {
  e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.RED);
}
```

Note that all the above are case-sensitive meaning an event named "vacation days" would not be colored. I would recommend instead lowercasing both your search word and the title before comparison. For example:

```
if (title.toLowerCase().includes("vacation")) {
  e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.RED);
}
```

Comment: Thank you mschwartz! I tried several of these and they worked as well! I accepted the other answer since they replied earlier, I hope that's okay but all of your solutions worked as well! Thank you for your time!